# Update the first six (of eight) cells in a row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update the contents of some of the cells of a row of a table via jQuery. Here's the structure of a typical row:

```
<tr>
  <td>2015-01-01</td>
  <td>09:00</td>
  <td>18:30</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Normal Day</td>
  <td>No comments</td>
  <td><a href=#><img src="edit.png" class="edit"></a></td> 
  <td><a href=#><img src="delete.png" class="delete"></a></td>   
</tr>
```

Earlier I had the row saved in a variable like this (when the edit button was clicked):

```
row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

The aim now, of course, is to update the cells with updated values (except for the icons). For this, I tried this:

```
$(':nth-child(1)', row).text(date);
$(':nth-child(2)', row).text(in_time);
$(':nth-child(3)', row).text(out_time);
$(':nth-child(4)', row).text(value);
$(':nth-child(5)', row).text(type);
$(':nth-child(6)', row).text(comments);
```

Although the first six cells are getting updated just fine, the last two are being converted into links with text of date. I guess it's happening because `$(':nth-child(1)', row).text(date)` is matching the `<img>` tag as the first child and replacing it.

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:eq()` instead of `:nth-child()`
Careful tho, `eq` index starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: Excellent! You've also helped me improve the earlier code. I'll accept this as the answer as soon as the system allows me (8 minutes :P).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right, `:nth-child(1)` targets all the first child descendants of the `row`.

You need to target only the `td` elements so adding a element selector should solve the problem

```
$('td:nth-child(1)', row).text(date);
```

or targeting only the children of `row`

```
row.children(':nth-child(1)').text(date);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. You've been a godsend once again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach also:

```
var i = 0;
$('td').each(function(){
    if(i < 5) {
    $(this).html('update ' + i);
        alert(i);
    }
    i++;
})
```